# How to find closest date in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Input:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2020-08-04</td>
        <td>12535.333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2020-08-10</td>
        <td>7946.010</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2020-08-14</td>
        <td>6888.944</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2020-08-27</td>
        <td>6212.944</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2020-08-29</td>
        <td>30278.756</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2020-09-02</td>
        <td>64079.236</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Expected-output:

```
<output>
  <p>6888.944</p>
</output>
```

Logic:

I want to get the `tr[6] (2020-09-02)` --> `td[1]` then I want to subtract `7` days. When subtracting 7 days from `2020-09-02` answer is `2020-08-26`. But in input, it is impossible to find `2020-08-26` in the input. Then It should select the closest date to `2020-08-26` from other `tr/td`. But the difference between `2020-09-02` and the closest date must be more than `7` days

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="table/tr[6]/tr[1]">
        <output id="{generate-id()}" type="SPNZX20Index">
            <xsl:call-template name="p-content">
                <xsl:with-param name="node" select="node()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="p-content">
        <xsl:param name="node"/>
        
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="tr:get-weekly-change(.)"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:function name="tr:get-weekly-change">
        <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
        
        <xsl:variable name="change" select="xs:date($node/preceding-sibling::*[1]) - 7*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/ancestor::xml/table/tr/td[1]">
            <xsl:if test=". = $change>
                <xsl:value-of select="parent::tr/td[3]"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:function>
```

My tried code not as I expected. I am using `XSLT 2.0`

Comment: You are not supposed to delete questions after you have received a working answer. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You want the *first preceding sibling* that has a time difference to the current node of 7 days or more.

No functions or separate templates are necessary, that can be expressed as a single XPath:

```
<xsl:template match="tr[6]">
    <output id="{generate-id()}" type="SPNZX20Index">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="
                preceding-sibling::tr[
                    xs:date(current()/td[1]) - xs:date(td[1]) &gt;= xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D')
                ][1]/td[2]
            " />
        </p>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Result

```
<output id="d10065e49" type="SPNZX20Index">
   <p>6888.944</p>
</output>
```

It's worth pointing out that when you select from "reverse" XPath axes (`preceding`, `preceding-sibling`, `ancestor`, technically even `parent`), then counting is reversed as well. `preceding-sibling::tr[1]` will select the node closest to the current node, not the first in the list. `(preceding-sibling::tr)[1]` would select the first in the list.